# Java placing text onto image not showing up

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, javax.imageio

Hey all I'm new to the world of Java so this is probably an easy one to solve but I am unable to find out what's wrong with it.

I am wanting to place some text onto an image I am creating. Problem being that once the image is saved and I look at it there is no text.

```
String tiffImg = "";    
String imgPath = "";
BufferedImage image = null;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected boolean saveTiff(String filename, BufferedImage image) {      
    File tiffFile = new File(filename);
    ImageOutputStream ios = null;
    ImageWriter writer = null;

    try {
        Iterator it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIF");

        if (it.hasNext()) {
            writer = (ImageWriter)it.next();
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(tiffFile);
        imgPath = tiffFile.getAbsolutePath();
        writer.setOutput(ios);
        TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.ENGLISH);
        writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        writeParam.setCompressionType("PackBits");
        IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
        writer.write(null, iioImage, writeParam);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;

    try {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decode(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return image;
}

public BufferedImage placeDataOnImage(BufferedImage image, String transNum) {       
    try {           
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));

        g.drawString(transNum, 150, 1350);
        g.drawString(transNum, 200, 2805);
        g.drawString(transNum, 200, 4453);

        g.drawString("DFDFFFF", 225, 590);
        g.drawString("rrrr", 225, 675);
        g.drawString("555-555-5555", 225, 718);

        g.drawString("Jocelyn", 767, 597);
        g.drawString("1-877-324-6427, ext. #", 767, 665);
        g.drawString("1-888-550-6427 (Toll Free)", 767, 701);

        g.drawString("11/28/18", 276, 800);
        g.drawString("11/28/18", 718, 799);
        g.drawString("2", 270, 837);

        g.drawString("sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf", 176, 1880);
        g.drawString("11/15/2018", 176, 1980);
        g.dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return image;
}

public String exec(ITestExecutionServices tes, String[] args) {        
    boolean savedImg = false;
    String currentTransID = args[0];

    image = decodeToImage(tiffImg);
    image = placeDataOnImage(image, currentTransID);
    savedImg = saveTiff(currentTransID + ".tiff", image);

    if (savedImg) {
        tes.getTestLogManager().reportVerificationPoint("TIFF created with Transaction ID# " + currentTransID, VerdictEvent.VERDICT_PASS);
    } else {
        tes.getTestLogManager().reportVerificationPoint("TIFF could not be created", VerdictEvent.VERDICT_ERROR);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Does anyone see where I may have done something wrong?

Comment: How large (width, height in pixels) is your image? What color does it have? Do you get a TIFF saved at all? What does it look like? You might want to include (or link to) the image you use in the test, and the result you get. Finally, why is `image` a member variable, rather than an instance variable in the `exec` method? Your code will behave very strange in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @haraldK its around 1224 x 4752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugg... just thought of something. I did not specify the color of the text and therefore I take it that it defaults to white - the whole reason I am unable to see it.

I added:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and magically it showed up on the image! Go figure....

Comment: That's why I asked what color your image had... ;-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't read you're full post. I stopped reading at what size is the image and never went back to read the rest :)